# Network hangs on 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking

Running 20.04 LTS on ASUS-VC66 w/Intel Core I7 processor, the network stops working 2 or 3 times a week.  Only solution seems to be rebooting.  The computer has both a WiFi connection and a wired Ethernet connection, and other devices on both of those networks can still communicate to outside world (e.g. ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) just fine.  I do have docker installed, which is my primary use for this machine (as a server running docker stacks).

Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350

For Nate's question, here's the ifconfig (or did you mean something else?) (hex addresses are obfuscated).  It should be the standard config, as I haven't made any changes, though I do have a VPN installed.  Outages don't seem to be correlated to that though.

```
ifconfig
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:6cff:fe75:5f41  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:6c:76:5f:41  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 43064  bytes 4525569 (4.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 79742  bytes 175862242 (175.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.84.46  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.84.255
        inet6 fe80::183b:65d2:d190:6024  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9c:5c:6e:20:69:c2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 844946  bytes 999444402 (999.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 396896  bytes 49634112 (49.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xf7100000-f7120000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4439  bytes 3291428 (3.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4439  bytes 3291428 (3.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1280
        inet 10.100.200.101  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 192.0.2.1
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 4928  bytes 2012655 (2.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10451  bytes 825637 (825.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth2ac72ae: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::8406:f9ff:fe67:4e5d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 86:06:f9:65:4e:5d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 354  bytes 1240651 (1.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 726  bytes 88209 (88.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.84.31  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.84.255
        inet6 fe80::22a3:4c48:a30d:dcfe  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 34:f3:7a:17:4b:e3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 461728  bytes 523928098 (523.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6310  bytes 1023600 (1.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    enter code here
```

Comment: One other thing I might mention is that I also use SonicWall NetExtender to connect to a VPN with this machine ... most of the time that works fine and the outages don't seem correlated but just wanted to include that fact.

Comment: Do you have it configured correctly?

Comment: Next time it happens, try `nmcli network off && nmcli network on` see if it resets the network without having to reboot.

Comment: Thanks @Raffles - I'll give that a try!  Definitely better than a reboot!